# Mockito & Robolectric - Test result of call and test next activity

Tags: android

I'm new to Android testing and I'm having some issues while testing that an activity opens another one after the result of an API call.

I'm pasting the code for the call and the callback invoked on success:

```
Api.get_instance(this).login(Constants.API_USER, Constants.API_PASSWORD, this, Constants.API_REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN);
```

When the answer comes back from the server:

```
 @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(int requestCode, List result) {
        ServiceResponse s;
        JSONObject j;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.API_REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN:
                s = (ServiceResponse) result.get(0);
                j = (JSONObject) s.get_extras();
                try {
                    ...
                    startHomeActivity();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

If everything is ok I call "startHomeActivity"

The problem is that while testing, I get a null pointer exception since the test does not wait for the response.

I've tried using mockito, but I get a Wanted but not invoked with the following code:

```
@Test
    public void afterSplash_shouldStartHomeActivity() {

        Mockito.verify(mockApi).login(Constants.API_USER, Constants.API_PASSWORD, new AsyncTaskCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(int requestCode, List result) {
                ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(activity);
                Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
                ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(startedIntent);
                Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, HomeActivity.class);
                assertEquals(shadowIntent, expectedIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskError(int requestCode, ServiceResponse error) {

            }
        }, Constants.API_REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN);


    }
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mockito.verify() will tell you if the method in question has been accessed by the application under test, but it will not execute it.

I suggest using the Http handling available in Robolectric *(shown here with 3.0+assertj. It's available in 2.4 too but with different class names)*. Queue an Http response that will be delivered at the next Http call. Then check that the correct activity is set to be launched.

```
@Test
public void afterSplash_shouldStartHomeActivity() {
 FakeHttp.addPendingHttpResponse(Constants.API_REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN, someHttpResponse);
 Api.get_instance(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext()).login(Constants.API_USER, Constants.API_PASSWORD, this, Constants.API_REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN);
 assertThat(ShadowApplication.getInstance().peekNextStartedActivity()).isInstanceOf(HomeActivity.class);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using volley, and it seems that it's not working that way, the results are still the same thenextStartedActivity is still null. I'll investigate to see how can I make this work, thanks a lot for the help. If you do know how to fix this please let me know!